# TypeError: comments.map is not a function react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I got an error when I select an object, currently comments files are stored in another file and I'm accessing it in this file but I got an error

> TypeError: comments.map is not a function

my code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";

function RenderDish({ dish }) {
  if (dish != null) {
    return (
      <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
        <Card>
          <CardImg width="100%" object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}></CardImg>
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
function RenderComments(comments) {
  if (comments != null) {
    const commentsList = comments.map((Comment) => {
      return (
        <div className="container">
          <li key={Comment.id}>
            <p>{Comment.Comment}</p>
            <p>
              -- {Comment.author},
              {new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", { year: "numeric", month: "short", day: "2-digit" }).format(new Date(Date.parse(Comment.id)))}
            </p>
          </li>
        </div>
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
        <h3>Comments</h3>
        <ul className="list-unstyled">{commentsList}</ul>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
const DishDetail = (props) => {
  console.log("Dishdetail Component render invoked");
  if (props.dish != null) {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <RenderDish dish={props.dish} />
        <RenderComments comments={props.dish.comments} />
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div></div>;
  }
};

export default DishDetail;
```

Comment: Is your comments' type is Array? to use map comments, it should be an array, not an object. log to the console your comments and check the type.

Comment: If your comment is of right type, it looks like by the time the render is invoked your props aren't ready to be rendered. instead of using `if(comments === null) { .... }  else { ...  }` you should try to render the component when you have props. You need to do something like `return (<div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1"><h3>Comments</h3><ul className="list-unstyled">{ /* do your check and return here */}</ul></div>)`;

Comment: Make sure the comment is an array

Comment: props.dish.comments doesn't seems to be an array

Answer (score 0):

You passing a prop and mapping the prop instead accessing it:

```
<RenderComments comments={props.dish.comments} />

// Not RenderComments(comments)
function RenderComments(props) {
  ...
  props.comments.map(...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error.

In my case, a single array item has been passed mistakenly by selecting index 0 instead of full-array in the main component.

`comments={this.state.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(match.params.dishId, 10))[0]}` in main component.

Corrected version:

```
const DishWithId = ({ match }) => {
        return (
            <DishDetail dish={this.state.dishes.filter((dish) => dish.id === parseInt(match.params.dishId, 10))[0]}
                comments={this.state.comments.filter((comment) => comment.dishId === parseInt(match.params.dishId, 10))} />
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that this answer is overkill.

Anything that you pass in like `comment={comment}` will be part of the props as an object, so you need to deconstruct comment from it.

You also do not need to return the empty div's during conditional rendering. Returning nothing is the same.

Also, `value != null` is insufficient. If the value is any other type of falsey, your app will still crash so `!value` is much safer.

If you are going to conditionally render inline, it is much easier to use `&&` or a ternary `? :` instead of a standard `if`.

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardText, CardBody, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";

const RenderDish = ({ dish }) => (
  dish && (
    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
      <Card>
        <CardImg width="100%" object src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}></CardImg>
        <CardBody>
          <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
          <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
        </CardBody>
      </Card>
    </div>
  )
);

const RenderComments = ({ comments }) => (
  comments && (
    <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
      <h3>Comments</h3>
      <ul className="list-unstyled">{
        comments.map(comment => (
          <div className="container">
            <li key={comment.id}>
              <p>{comment.comment}</p>
              <p>
                -- {comment.author},
                {new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-US", {
                  year: "numeric",
                  month: "short",
                  day: "2-digit"
                }).format(new Date(Date.parse(comment.id)))}
              </p>
            </li>
          </div>
        ))
      }</ul>
    </div>
  )
);

const DishDetail = ({ dish }) => (
  dish && (
    <div className="row">
      <RenderDish dish={dish} />
      <RenderComments comments={dish.comments} />
    </div>
  )
);

export default DishDetail;
```